# Why are there always pairwise intersections in a Heegaard splitting?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, low-dimensional-topology

Let $M=A\cup B$ be a Heegaard splitting, such that $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^g$ is a set of boundaries for meridian disks of $A$, and $\{\beta_i\}_{i=1}^g$ is a set of boundaries for meridian disks of $B$ (Recall that meridian disks are those properly embedded in the manifold, and such that the union of their boundaries doesn't separate the boundary of said manifold).

Why is it true that we can always find a permutation $\tau$ of $\{1,...,g\}$ such that $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_{\tau(i)}$ intersect? Moreover, if I'm not mistaken, once we've found such pairwise intersections for a subset of the $\alpha$'s, we can complete it to the rest of the $\alpha$'s (so that in the end each $\alpha$ intersects some $\beta$, and vice versa). Why is this possible?

Edit: It appears that this is not true in general, however it is true, for example, in the case of the rational homology sphere. I would like to understand why in this particular case the statement is true.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you always can find such a permutation. For example take the genus one splitting of $S^1 \times S^2$. You can take your $\alpha$,$\beta$ curves to be parallel (and hence non-intersecting) meridians of a torus.

Comment: @Bambi; You are right. Is there some assumption (except for the obvious) we can add so that this statement would be correct?

Comment: I think it should be true if your manifold is a rational homology sphere, i.e. the first homology is finite.

Comment: @Bambi, that would certainly help since I mainly need the result for this case. Could you elaborate why it is true then? (I'll edit the question.)

Comment: I don't have time now, but I'll write you up an answer later.

Comment: @Bambi - I don't mean to bother you, but I thought I'd remind you of this question in case you have some time now. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, I totally forgot about this. You should have reminded me before!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I noted in the comments above, what you originally asked is not true - the standard genus one splitting of $S^1 \times S^2$ does not have an intersection between its $\alpha$ and $\beta$ curve. However, it does hold for rational homology spheres.

We take a Heegard splitting for $M$ with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ curves $(\alpha_i)_{i=1}^g$, $(\beta_j)_{j=1}^g$. We can consider this Heegard splitting as a handle decomposition of $M$, where the $\alpha$ curves are belt disks if 1-handles and the $\beta$ curves are are the attaching disks for the 2-handles. This means that $H_1(M)$ is presented by the matrix $A=(\alpha_i \cdot \beta_j)_{1\leq i,j\leq g}$, where $\alpha_i \cdot \beta_j$, is the *algebraic* intersection of the $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_j$.

In particular, if $M$ is a rational homology sphere, then $|H_1(M)|=|\det(A)|> 0$.

Consider the expression coming from the definition of the determinant (see wikipedia link below):
$$|\det(A)|= |\sum_{\sigma \in S_g} \epsilon(\sigma) \prod_{1\leq i\leq g}\alpha_i \cdot \beta_{\sigma(i)}|,$$
where $\epsilon(\sigma)=\pm 1$ is the *sign* of the permutation $\sigma$. Now since $\det A \ne 0$, this shows there exists $\sigma \in S_g$ such that $\prod_{1\leq i\leq g}\alpha_i \cdot \beta_{\sigma(i)}\ne 0$. So for this $\sigma$, $\alpha_i \cdot \beta_{\sigma(i)}\ne 0$ for $1\leq i \leq g$. Since algebraic intersection non-zero implies geometric intersection non-zero, this is the permutation you want.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#n.C2.A0.C3.97.C2.A0n_matrices

Comment: In somewhat of a delay: I re-read your answer now, and although back then it seemed to me that I understood it, I am now confused -- could you add an explanation about why the first homology group is presented by this matrix?

Comment: I can think of two ways to explain this. Both require non-trivial algebraic topology. The first is to consider cellular homology. This is what I'm using in the sentence beginning "If we consider the Heegaard splitting as a handle decomposition...". A handle decomposition is just a "fattened up" cell decomposition. In cellular homology the 2nd boundary maps counts how many times the attaching map of each 2-cell winds around each  1-cell (See Hatcher p.140, for example). When you fatten-up to handles, rather than cells, the attaching maps of the 2-cells become the $\beta$ curves and

Comment: counting how many times they wind around the 1-cells is the same counting the intersection number with the $\alpha$ curves (which can be viewed as fattened up mid points of 1-cells. Thus the boundary map with respect this handle decomposition is given by that matrix.

Comment: The other way to see this fact is to use this handle decomposition to give you a presentation for the fundamental group and then use the fact that $H_1$ is the abelianisation of the fundamental group (Hatcher, Theorem 2A.1). The presentation for $\pi_1$ is the one where you take one generator for each 1-handle, that is each $\alpha$ curve. You then add one relation for each $\beta$ curve, which just records each $\alpha$ -curve that the $\beta$ curve traverses.  When you abelianise this relation you just end up with a relation corresponding to the rows of the intersection matrix.

Comment: I hope some of this helped. Really both approaches need some pictures.

Comment: Great, thanks! The second one is nice and simple, and I actually thought about the first one before, but couldn't visualize how the intersection points give the degree of the attaching map in the case of high genus. In genus 1 it's trivial, but once a beta curve intersects different alpha curves it became less intuitive.

Comment: By the way, from your wording it seems that one can consider a Heegaard splitting as something other than a handle decomposition. What do you mean by that?

Comment: Great. I like the second one too, but I wasn't sure how much algebraic topology I could assume.

So the other thing I was talking about was a cell decomposition. As in describing the manifold as a CW-complex. By 'shrinking' the handles onto their cores you get a cell decomposition for the manifold. This was because I wasn't sure whether you were maybe familiar with cellular homology, but not with computing homology from a handle decomposition. If you're happy with the handle decompositions and the corresponding homology maps, then you can ignore the comments about cells.