# Computing homology from a Heegaard Splitting

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

I've recently begun thinking a little about Heegaard splittings and Heegaard diagrams for closed orientable 3 manifolds. I'd like to understand:

> Given a Heegaard diagram for $Y$, can one 'read off' $H_{1}(Y)$ and $H_{2}(Y)$?

Ideally, 'read off' would mean something like apply an algorithm to a Heegaard diagram $(\Sigma, \{\alpha_{i}\}, \{\beta_{i}\})$ which describes the groups via generators and relations phrased in terms of the $\alpha_{i}$ and $\beta_{i}$.

Applying Mayer-Vietoris to the Heegaard decomposition $Y= M_{1} \cup_{\Sigma}M_{2}$, one finds it is sufficient to understand the map $(i_{1},i_{2})_{*} : H_{1}(\Sigma) \rightarrow H_{1}(M_{1}) \oplus H_{1}(M_{2})$ induced by the inclusions, as $H_{1}(Y) \cong coker((i_{1},i_{2})_{*})$ and $H_{2}(Y) \cong ker((i_{1},i_{2})_{*})$.

If I assume the $\alpha_{i}$ are chosen "nicely", I've been able to write down a matrix presenting this map. In the general case, I believe I can do the same so long as the following claim is true:

> Given a Heegaard diagram $(\Sigma, \{\alpha_{i}\}, \{\beta_{i}\})$, there exist curves $\{a_{i}\}$ and $\{b_{i}\}$ in $\Sigma$ such that $a_{i} \cap \alpha_{j} = \{pt\} \delta_{ij}$, $b_{i} \cap \beta_{j} = \{pt\} \delta_{ij}$,  and $\{a_{i}, b_{i}\}$ generate $H_{1}(\Sigma)$.

In all examples I've considered, it's easy to do this. Need this be true? Or is there an easy way to use M.V. to answer the original question?

Edit: I have seen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578428/why-are-there-always-pairwise-intersections-in-a-heegaard-splitting) post, and now understand the presentation given for $H_{1}(Y)$, which is very nice. I'd still like to understand how to write this down directly from M.V., since that seems to me like a natural method of attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find this in Section 3.5. of Jesse Johnson's notes: http://users.math.yale.edu/~jj327/notes.pdf

Comment: As far as I can tell, his proof is not via Mayer Vietoris, and in fact appears to be the same argument as that I linked to above. I'm accepting this answer anyway though, since these are a huge help, and I've been able to figure out the M.V. approach. Thanks!

Comment: Link is down. It seems you can find the document [here](https://dokumen.tips/documents/jesse-johnson-notes-on-heegaard-splittings.html).